# Get bad request from Google calendar API

Tags: c++, qt, google-calendar-api, bad-request

I'm trying to insert an event to google calendar using Qt C++.

Before inserting events, I am able to clear the primary calendar using these lines

```
const QUrl clearPrimaryUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/clear");

void GoogleWrapper::clearPrimaryCalendar()
{
    QNetworkReply *reply = google.post(clearPrimaryUrl);
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [=]()
    {
        reply->deleteLater();
        if(reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)
        {
            qCritical() << "Google error:" << reply->errorString();
            return;
        }
        emit primaryCalendarCleared();
    });
}
```

`google` is an [QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qoauth2authorizationcodeflow.html) object.
Now to insert events, I use these lines:

```
const QUrl insertEventUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events");
void GoogleWrapper::insertEvent(const QByteArray &eventData)
{
    qDebug() << eventData;
    QNetworkReply *reply = google.post(insertEventUrl, eventData);
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [=]()
    {
        reply->deleteLater();
        if(reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)
        {
            qCritical() << "Google error:" << reply->errorString();
            return;
        }
        emit eventInserted();
    });
}
```

But the output I received from qCritical was always `Error transferring https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events - server replied: Bad Request`.
I tried output the `eventData` to a file and copy paste it to [Google's try this API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#try-it) and the below json data works perfectly

```
{
    "description": "some teacher name",
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2018-12-19T11:15:00Z"
    },
    "location": "Room",
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2018-12-19T09:30:00Z"
    },
    "summary": "Subject Name"
}
```

Anyone have any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: Have you set the content type to `JSON` ?`google.setContentType(QAbstractOAuth2::ContentType::Json);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved thanks to @thuga's comment.

My code was missing the line

```
google.setContentType(QAbstractOAuth2::ContentType::Json);
```